# Solution of $x''+q (t)x=0$ is strictly convex over $[0, + \infty [$ if $q $ does not vanish over $ [0, + \infty [\setminus D $ where D is a discrete?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $ q: [0, + \infty [\to \Bbb R $ continuous such that $ q (t) \leq 0 $ on $ [0, + \infty [$. Consider the differential equation $$ x '' + qx = 0 \qquad (*) $$ let $ \psi $ be a solution of $(*)$ on $ [0, + \infty [$ verifying the initial condition $ \psi ( 0) = $ 0, $ \psi '(0) = $ 1. Suppose that $ q $ does not vanish over $ [0, + \infty [\setminus D $ where D is a discrete subset. Can we say that $ \psi $ is strictly convex over $[0, + \infty [? $

Answer (score 0):

Let $\psi \in C^2((0,\infty) \cap C^1([0,\infty)) $. We begin by arguing that $\psi >0$ in $(0,\infty)$. Observe that since $\psi(0)=0$ and $\psi'(0)=1>0$, there exists some $\varepsilon >0$ such that $\psi>0$ in $(0,\varepsilon)$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there exists some $T>0$ such that $\psi(T)=0$. By Rolle's Theorem, there must exist a point critical point somewhere in $[0,T]$ and since $\psi$ begins off positive, $\psi$ must be attain a positive maximum somewhere in $[0,T]$. However, by the strong maximum principle (noting that $q\leqslant 0$), if $\psi$ attains a positive maximum in $[0,T]$ then it must be a constant, which contradicts the initial conditions.

Once we have $\psi >0$ in $(0,\infty)$ then we just rearrange $(\ast)$ to conclude $$ \psi'' = -q\psi \geqslant 0 $$ in $(0,\infty)$ and $$ \psi'' > 0  $$ in $(0,\infty) \backslash D$. Since $D$ is a discrete set of point and so has measure zero, this implies $\psi$ is strictly convex on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: But $q $ does not vanish over $ [0,+\infty[\setminus D$ where D. And you consider it not vanish over $[0,+\infty[$

Comment: No, I did not assume $q>0$ on $(0,\infty)$. This is why I said "except for a discrete set of points". I will edit my answer to make this clearer.